# Redis Twitter-like Follow/Unfollow Design Pattern

Tags: algorithm, architecture, nosql, redis, twitter-follow

Suppose we are duplicating the Twitter's follow function. As far as I can tell, everyone now agrees to the following design using Redis.

All tweets followed by joe are stored in a sorted set "ss:joe" with key=tweet_id, score=tweet_timestamp

So when joe follows ladygaga, ladygaga's tweets are added to "ss:joe", so far so good.

The question is: how do I remove ladygaga's tweets from "ss:joe" when joe unfollows ladygaga?

Iterating through every single "ss:joe" tweet and remove those that belong to ladygaga is out.

The best I can think of is to maintain another sorted set for every user storing her own tweets, so ladygaga will have her sorted set "tweets:ladygaga" with key=tweet_id, score=tweet_timestamp, then we can pick out ladygaga's tweets by ZINTERSTORE "ss:joe" and "tweets:ladygaga".

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an even bigger problem to this design. Storing the `tweet_id`s in `ss:joe` means that the system cannot account for `gaga` creating a new tweet (or deleting one, if that is supported) without also modifying `ss:joe`. Now imagine having a few hundred celebs with 50,000 followers each, and each writing a dozen tweets per day. That's a lot of inserts into a lot of sets, which you cannot easily distribute either. And, it's a lot of duplicate data (remember redis is a RAM-only database, and although RAM gets cheaper it's still nowhere near "unlimited"). *EDIT: And for updating follower records, you need to know the followers too (since iterating over every user on every newly written tweet is hardly an option). So you need to maintain a list of backlinks as well.*

An alternative design would be to store the user ID of the followed person in a set (or sorted set, if you will, so the user can shuffle the order). Each person further has a sorted set with all their tweet IDs (sorted by date).

This will require an additional query *per followed person* to get the tweet IDs, but it will reduce unfollowing to removing one value from a set, and it will keep everyone updated automatically as new tweets are created.

Lookups are less costly than inserts/removes (which may require rebalancing or rehashing), so even if you follow a dozen people, those extra queries probably aren't as much of an issue as would be more frequent updates.
Plus, lookups can actually happen on a network of replicated slaves (a second or two may pass before a new tweet is visible to everyone, but who cares -- it scales infinitely).

Comment: Excellent point. So does anyone know if this is how Twitter is actually implemented? But is there any way to reduce the 100 round trips on _every_ GET if on average people follow 100 others? How about those nuts who follow 2,000? I still find it hard to imagine sending 2,000 Redis reads on every request, especially when those nuts are more likely to be active users who would make a lot more fuss if the system takes more than 2 seconds to respond.

Comment: Well, you could still always cache the data (do the same as you proposed, but temporarily) to reduce round trips, if they're an issue. Redis has a TTL feature, so you could fetch the tweet IDs once and write them to e.g. `c:joe` and give it a TTL of one minute. If no `c:joe` key exists, fetch them anew. Thus joe will see gaga's newest tweet with at most 1 minute delay, but the perceived reaction time is fast and you only do the round trip at most once per user per minute and only use memory for currently active users. Or, just use memcached, which most dynamic high-traffic sites use anyway.

Comment: As to how Twitter is really implemented, I doubt anyone will be able to tell you such details. The people who do know will be under NDA for sure.

Comment: Phew, it was this close that I would have started the wrong implementation had I not seen your answer. Thank you so much Damon!